# Is there any way I can scrape/grab the "about" section of a google search?

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart, web-scraping

I am building out an flutter app for school that lists dog breeds. I am wondering if it is possible to pull down the "about section" for a google search query. I am using flutter/dart but I think this question is language agnostic, I just want to know if it's possible. This is what I am talking about:
[image]

I want to grab the paragraph under the "about" header. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use this API from Google https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph

Comment: Thank you, now I just need to figure out how I can access these nested JSON elements in dart...

Comment: @Connor You are welcome) With JSON you can start from here - https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json

Answer (score 1):

However, there's a lots of ways you can do this. One way you can use this API called [SerpApi](https://serpapi.com/)

This returns the results in `Json`

Just SignUp in this service. and with `http` package you can get results like so

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

var url = Uri.parse('https://serpapi.com/search');
var query = "Samoyed" // Your query;

var response = await http.get(url + "?q=$query&google_domain=google.com&api_key=secret_api_key");

print(response.body);
```

You'll get

```
"knowledge_graph":
{
"title":
"Samoyed",
"type":
"Dog breed",
"header_images":
[
{
"image":
"https://serpapi.com/searches/619669ffc47d3ccfb5511aa1/images/1dbd475a36109a83173d2d6a380adb0cd740843c4a06be6455a87b252b4811b3f717889baa84eb34.jpeg",
"source":
"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samoyed_dog"
},
{
"image":
"https://serpapi.com/searches/619669ffc47d3ccfb5511aa1/images/1dbd475a36109a83173d2d6a380adb0cd740843c4a06be6477e61734e5c35299fd9ba84a832499c2.jpeg",
"source":
"https://www.akc.org/dog-breeds/samoyed/"
},
{
"image":
"https://serpapi.com/searches/619669ffc47d3ccfb5511aa1/images/1dbd475a36109a83173d2d6a380adb0cd740843c4a06be641d71587a667af36fd5c22ede97ad0d5d.jpeg",
"source":
"https://www.thesprucepets.com/samoyed-dog-breed-profile-4586270"
},
{
"image":
"https://serpapi.com/searches/619669ffc47d3ccfb5511aa1/images/1dbd475a36109a83173d2d6a380adb0cd740843c4a06be6407d380d689b958ece6cfa86598a2b35e.jpeg",
"source":
"https://www.rover.com/blog/samoyed-puppies-complete-guide/"
},
{
"image":
"https://serpapi.com/searches/619669ffc47d3ccfb5511aa1/images/1dbd475a36109a83173d2d6a380adb0cd740843c4a06be64097c7c54fd3dce6ea08aeb17527d8bfa.jpeg",
"source":
"https://www.dailypaws.com/dogs-puppies/dog-breeds/samoyed"
},
{
"image":
"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTDUBrb001EttjCvMAByRCKQvioc2KHy6rD7McCmeJ1wg&s",
"source":
"http://www.vetstreet.com/dogs/samoyed"
}
],
"description":
"The Samoyed is a breed of medium-sized herding dogs with thick, white, double-layer coats. They are a spitz-type dog which takes its name from the Samoyedic peoples of Siberia.",
"source":
{
"name":
"Wikipedia",
"link":
"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samoyed_dog"
},....
```